# Using regex to parse unit, amount and name out of string

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

What I currently have:

```
    val unitRegex = """(\d+(\s+\d+/\d+)?)?\s*(tbsp|tsp|lbs|lb|pinch|stalk|stalks|oz|cup|cups|pint|pints|quart|quarts|gallon|gallons|ml|milliliter|milliliters|l|liter|liters|g|gram|grams|kg|kilogram|kilograms|fl oz|fluid ounce|fluid ounces|teaspoon|teaspoons|tablespoon|tablespoons)?\s*(.+)""".toRegex()
    val ingredientsList = mutableListOf<RecipeIngredients>()

    for (ingredient in allIngredients) {
        unitRegex.find(ingredient.trim())?.let { matchResult ->
            val (amount, _, unit, ingredientName) = matchResult.destructured
            //val ingredientName = ingredient.substringAfterLast(matchResult.value).trim()
            ingredientsList.add(
                RecipeIngredients(
                    name = ingredientName
                        .replace(Regex("[.()]|\\boptional\\b", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE), "")
                        .removeParenthesizedSubstring()
                        .removeAfterComma()
                        .trim(),
                    unit = unit.trim(),
                    amount = amount.trim(),
                    isOptional = ingredientName.contains("optional", ignoreCase = true),
                    isMissing = showMissingIngredients && missedIngredients.contains(
                        ingredientName
                    ),
                    image = ingredientName.mapDetectedIngredientImage()
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to split string into - amount, unit and name.
For instance: "1 1/2 lbs cauliflower" with this code is transformed as "1 1/2" as an amount, "lbs" as unit and "cauliflower" as a name, but sadly, it does not work for "1/2 cups water" -> "1" as amount, unit is empty and name is "/2 cup water". Any idea what is wrong with my regex?

More example of strings that I pass:

```
1½ cups mayonnaise
¾ tbsp Dijon mustard
¾ tbsp cider vinegar
1 pinch salt
1 pinch ground black pepper
1½ lbs cauliflower
salt and ground black pepper
½ cup water
5 oz. bacon
3 (4¼ oz.) celery stalks
½ (2 oz.) red onion
2 tbsp fresh chives
```

Comment: Why are in your sample code unicode fracture signs like `½` whereas your regex let's assume your data contains `1/2`. Can you update your question please to make this more clear? I guess you want something like [`^(\d+(?:/\d+| +\d+/\d+)?)`...](https://regex101.com/r/B8tC51/1) for the digits part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify quantity parsing:

- add optional group to match a leading integer part of the quantity, followed by whitespace,
- add capturing group for fractions that includes both simple numeric fractions `(\d+/\d+)` and Unicode fractions `([\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E])`:

```kotlin
val unitRegex = """(?:(\d+)\s+)?((?:\d+/\d+)|[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E])?\s*(tbsp|tsp|lbs|lb|pinch|stalk|stalks|oz|cup|cups|pint|pints|quart|quarts|gallon|gallons|ml|milliliter|milliliters|l|liter|liters|g|gram|grams|kg|kilogram|kilograms|fl oz|fluid ounce|fluid ounces|teaspoon|teaspoons|tablespoon|tablespoons)?\s*(.+)""".toRegex()
```